# Finding average of last column

Tags: java

So i need the program to print out the averages of the average temperatures of each week but i cannot find a solution on how to do so. Currently i have the column that prints out the averages of the temperatures of the week as a `System.out.print`, so its not in the 2d array but now i need to find the average of those averages. I tried using `System.out.print(average/4);` to find the averages but the number it prints out isn't correct. How should i write the code for this ?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDimArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // 1) Declare and allocate Storage
        //Each day name is assigned to the array as a String so each name must be enclosed in apostrophes and each string must be separated by commas.
        String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
        double[][] Temperature = new double[4][7];

        // 2) Populate Array
        for (int i = 0; i < Temperature.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Temperature[0].length; j++) {
                //days[j] will print the proper day and "(i+1)" will print the proper day of the week
                System.out.print("Enter " + days[j] + " Temperature " + "for Week " + (i + 1) + ": " + "    ");
                Temperature[i][j] = scan.nextDouble();
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("              Weekly Temperature Report ");
        System.out.println("Mon     Tue     Wed     Thurs    Fri    Sat     Sun    Average");

        double columnTotal, average;
        // 4) Output Array

        for (int i = 0; i < Temperature.length; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            columnTotal = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < Temperature[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(Temperature[i][j] + "\t");
                columnTotal += Temperature[i][j];
            }
            average = columnTotal / 7;
            System.out.println(average);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");
        int avg;
        for (int i = 0; i < Temperature[0].length; i++) {
            columnTotal = 0;
            avg = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < Temperature.length; j++) {
                columnTotal = columnTotal + Temperature[j][i];

            }
            System.out.print((columnTotal / 4) + "    ");
            System.out.print(average / 4);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does _the number it prints out isn't correct_ mean?  Provide sample input, actual output, and expected output.  Try doing the math manually on paper, then translate to code.  Use a debugger to step through the loops and watch the calculations to make sure they match the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok do the following changes in ur code

1. Declare The array of average `average[] = new double[Temperature.length];`
2. Replace this  `average = columnTotal / 7`;`System.out.println(average);`with this

   `average[i] = columnTotal / 7 ;` `System.out.println(average[i]);`
   so what i am doing storing the averages in array . you were storing the average in a simple variable which was overwritten again and again till the end of loop
3. And at the end replace the last part of code with

   columnTotal = 0;

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < average.length; i++) {
           columnTotal = columnTotal +average[i];
       }
       System.out.print((columnTotal / 4) + "    ");
   ```

And Finally Your code will look like this

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDimArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // 1) Declare and allocate Storage
        //Each day name is assigned to the array as a String so each name must be enclosed in apostrophes and each string must be separated by commas.
        String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
        double[][] Temperature = new double[4][7];

        // 2) Populate Array
        for (int i = 0; i < Temperature.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Temperature[0].length; j++) {
                //days[j] will print the proper day and "(i+1)" will print the proper day of the week
                System.out.print("Enter " + days[j] + " Temperature " + "for Week " + (i + 1) + ": " + "    ");
                Temperature[i][j] = scan.nextDouble();
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("              Weekly Temperature Report ");
        System.out.println("Mon     Tue     Wed     Thurs    Fri    Sat     Sun    Average");

        double columnTotal, average[] = new double[Temperature.length];
        // 4) Output Array

        for (int i = 0; i < Temperature.length; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            columnTotal = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < Temperature[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(Temperature[i][j] + "\t");
                columnTotal += Temperature[i][j];
            }
            average[i] = columnTotal / 7;
            System.out.println(average[i]);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");

        columnTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < average.length; i++) {
                columnTotal = columnTotal +average[i];
            }
            System.out.print((columnTotal / 4) + "    ");
            //System.out.print(average/4);

        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks so much. I was thinking that making average an array would work but wasnt sure on how it would. Thanks again.